# localStorage.clear not working properly in Wp

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, hook, wordpress-hook

I want to clear `window.localStorage.clear` after login and logout. I have added this code in the functions.php but it's not working. How can I overcome this?

```
add_action(' wp_logout ',' auto_redirect_external_after_logout ');
function auto_redirect_external_after_logout(){
    echo '<script>window.localStorage.clear();</script>';
    exit();
}

function do_anything() {
    echo '<script>window.localStorage.clear();</script>';
}
add_action('wp_login', 'do_anything');
```

Comment: What is the HTML that you get after you logout? I suggest you to trigger it from client browser instead. When a user clicks logout, clear the localStorage and then send the request to the server. Same goes with login.

Comment: @vivek_23 I am used this `<a class="dropdown-item" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>">Sign Out</a> ` for logout. How can I use javascript  in the logout function?

Comment: can you show your login and logout button/link code?

Answer (score 0):

I think echo in PHP will only output the string but it won't execute the JS which is inside the string. Hence your localStorage is not getting cleared. Otherwise the syntax you wrote for clearing localStorage is right.

Comment: JavaScript written to the page with PHP is no different than writing JavaScript in a static html page. If the JS is valid, it will execute.

Answer (score 0):

***A*** bug in the sample code (which may be the only reason it's not working as desired) is the whitespace in the two string literals that are IDs:

```
add_action(' wp_logout ',' auto_redirect_external_after_logout ');
```

Should be

```
add_action('wp_logout', 'auto_redirect_external_after_logout');
```

The whitespace on the event name means your hook is attached to an event nobody's sending, and I'd expect the extra spaces around the function name to result in "registered function not found".

(I'm reading ./wp-includes/plugin.php and class-wp-hook.php, and it all flows to a call to php-builtin [call_user_func()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).)